# Cannot Find File with NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to find a file with NSFileManager. The file exists but my path is never correct no matter how its phrased. The code I'm using is below. Why is NSFileManager not finding the file?

```
NSString      *myFile      = @"file1658.pdf";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFile]) {
    NSLog(@"good");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyFile` is not a full path (e.g., "/Users/Joe/Documents/file1658.pdf"), so `NSFileManager` is looking for it in the current working directory. You can see what that is with `-[NSFileManager currentDirectoryPath]`.

You need to either include the full path to the file as part of `myFile`, or set the proper working directory with `-[NSFileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:]`.

```
// If myFile is in "/Users/joe/Documents"...
[fileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/joe/Documents"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myFile]) {
    NSLog(@"good");
}
```

Comment: Full path was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple tries hard to get you to put your files in sensible places. The file my exist, but you will have to either give the full path, e.g. /Users/user2759189/file1658.pdf or specify what folder it is in by other means.

### App bundle

If the file is in your app bundle (for example, you have added it using "Add files to [project]" in XCode) you can get its path by something like:

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file1658" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

### Search paths

You can look for user documents in a civilised manner by using the foundation function [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) and some built in constants. If the file is in the user's Documents folder, for example, you can use something like:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file1658.pdf"];
```

Comment: Alerting the *myFile as suggested using pathForResource does not work. The file is in the app bundle.

Comment: OK. I have just tested the above code (with pdf instead of png -- oops) and it works for me. You can check under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources to see if the file will actually be copied into the app bundle.